# Scaling and positioning a new path element on a raphael.js paper

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael

I have a world map using raphael.js with a few countries highlighted using paths.  My client has asked that I add China as a highlighted country.  I located another raphael.js map with China in it and imported the coordinates.

It worked fine except that the position of the vector and it's size are not correct for the world map I am using.  The z-index appears to also need to be increased.

I can bring element up by calling `thismap.world.cn.toFront();` after it is drawn but the other elements do not require this so I am assuming I can adjust z-index with a coordinate edit?

Is it possible to manually scale and position the element?  Are there GUI tools for manipulating the coordinates or do I need to use scale() in raphael.js to manipulate the element?

Coords look like

```
cn: "M777.533,179.567l-2.325,1.451l-2.326-0.871v-2.323l1.163-1.453l3.196-0.581h1.455l0.581,0.872l-1.163,1.451L777.533,179.567zM825.204,94.194l4.651,0.871l3.488,1.742l0.871,2.614h4.361l2.325-0.872l4.651-0.871l-1.454,2.323l-1.163,1.162l-0.871,2.904l-2.034,2.613l-3.198-0.291l-2.325,0.871l0.581,2.324l-0.29,3.194l-1.454,0.291v1.161l-1.744-1.451l-1.163,1.451l-4.067,1.162l0.289,1.453h-2.325l-1.452-0.872l-1.745,2.032l-3.198,1.453l-2.033,1.742l-3.781,0.871l-2.033,1.162l-3.197,0.871l1.452-1.453l-0.58-1.16l2.325-1.742l-1.455-1.453l-2.324,1.162l-3.197,1.742l-1.745,1.742l-2.615,0.291l-1.452,1.16l1.452,1.743l2.326,0.581v1.162l2.325,0.872l2.906-2.033l2.616,1.162h1.744l0.289,1.452l-3.777,0.871l-1.454,1.452l-2.615,1.453l-1.453,1.742l3.196,1.742l0.872,2.614l1.743,2.613l1.745,2.033v2.033l-1.745,0.581l0.873,1.453l1.455,0.87l-0.292,2.324l-0.873,2.323h-1.452l-2.034,3.194l-2.326,3.484l-2.327,3.195l-3.778,2.613l-4.069,2.323l-2.905,0.291l-1.744,1.162l-0.873-0.871l-1.743,1.452l-3.779,1.451l-2.906,0.291l-0.872,2.904l-1.454,0.29l-0.873-2.033l0.584-1.162l-3.488-0.872l-1.455,0.581l-2.615-0.87l-1.454-0.873l0.581-1.742l-2.615-0.581l-1.452-0.871l-2.328,1.451l-2.615,0.291h-2.034l-1.454,0.58l-1.453,0.582l0.29,2.903h-1.455l-0.289-0.581v-1.161l-2.034,0.87l-1.163-0.581l-2.035-1.162l0.872-2.033l-1.743-0.581l-0.873-2.613l-2.905,0.58l0.29-3.484l2.615-2.323l0.291-2.033l-0.291-2.323l-1.161-0.581l-0.873-1.452h-1.455l-3.194-0.291l1.161-1.161l-1.455-1.743l-2.034,1.162l-2.033-0.581l-3.198,1.742l-2.615,2.033l-2.326,0.29l-1.162-0.872h-1.453l-2.035-0.58l-1.454,0.58l-1.743,2.033l-0.292-2.033l-1.744,0.582L713,154.013l-2.906-0.581l-2.326-1.162l-2.034-0.581l-1.162-1.452l-1.454-0.291l-2.615-1.742l-2.326-0.871l-1.162,0.581l-3.781-2.033l-2.615-1.742l-0.873-2.904l2.036,0.291v-1.453l-1.163-1.161l0.293-2.324l-2.908-3.194l-4.361-1.161l-0.87-2.033l-2.036-1.451l-0.58-0.582l-0.292-1.742v-1.161l-1.743-0.582l-0.874,0.291l-0.579-2.324l0.579-0.871l-0.289-0.581l2.615-1.162l2.036-0.58l2.906,0.291l0.871-1.744l3.489-0.29l1.162-1.162l4.362-1.451l0.289-0.581l-0.289-1.743l2.033-0.581l-2.617-4.646l5.524-1.162l1.452-0.58l2.034-4.938l5.232,0.873l1.744-1.162v-2.904l2.328-0.291l2.033-1.742l1.163-0.29l0.581,2.032l2.326,1.452l4.067,0.872l1.746,2.323l-0.873,3.194l0.873,1.162l3.197,0.582l3.778,0.29l3.488,1.742l1.743,0.291l1.163,2.613l1.455,1.453h3.196l5.522,0.58l3.78-0.291l2.615,0.291l4.069,1.743h3.489l1.162,0.871l3.197-1.451l4.361-0.873l4.359-0.29l3.198-0.871l1.745-1.452l2.033-0.871l-0.581-0.872l-0.873-1.161l1.454-1.742l1.745,0.29l2.614,0.581l2.908-1.452l4.069-1.162l2.034-1.742l2.035-0.872l4.07-0.29l2.034,0.29l0.291-1.162l-2.325-1.741l-2.326-0.872l-2.036,0.872l-2.904-0.291l-1.455,0.291l-0.581-1.162l1.744-2.613l1.453-2.324l3.197,1.162l4.068-1.742v-1.162l2.328-2.903l1.452-0.872v-1.452l-1.452-0.871l2.325-1.162l3.486-0.58h3.491l4.067,0.58l2.617,1.162l1.744,2.903l0.871,1.161l0.874,1.453L825.204,94.194z",
```

And current map with China drawn looks like:

[image: China]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the translate(x,y) method eg

`thismap.world.cn.translate(300, 100)`;

and the scale() method.